# How to get dropped duplicates index of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Im' using `df = df.drop_duplicates(["col1",["col2"])` on my pandas dataframe, but I need to know the dropped rows index, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) only for indices:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1] * 4, 'col2':[2,2,3,2]})
print (df)
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     1     2
2     1     3
3     1     2
    
print (df.drop_duplicates(["col1","col2"]))
   col1  col2
0     1     2
2     1     3
```

---

```
mask = df.duplicated(["col1","col2"])
idx = df.index[mask]
print (idx)
Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64')
```

Or use [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) if already removed duplicates:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(["col1","col2"])
idx = df.index.difference(df1.index)
print (idx)
Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: i think it might be good to note that last solution is good as it isn't computing duplicates again but doesn't work if index is not unique to begin with, e.g., for `df = df.append(df)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
dups = df.duplicated(["col1", "col2"])
dups[dups].index
```

First line gives a boolean array that marks if a row is duplicated or not. Second line uses boolean indexing against itself to choose `True` entries and we get the indices of them.